# Unable to display images in .thumbs directory with Apache 2.4, Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, apache2

Not necessarily a Magento question but using Apache 2.4 and Magento 2, the HTML editor image uploader creates a directory

```
pub/media/wysiwyg/.thumbs
```

Which our server can't display.  Error is

```
[Thu Feb 23 21:35:52.824316 2017] [access_compat:error] [pid 17097] [client XXXXX:43009] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/XXXXXXXX/pub/media/wysiwyg/.thumbs/XXXX.png
```

Vhost is

```
<Directory "/var/www/XXXXX/pub">
 Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Options +Indexes
            Options +MultiViews
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I know that's not Apache 2.4 but we're using access_compat to allow the old syntax.  I've been playing with the autoindex.conf but haven't been able to find the solution.

Anyone solves this yet?  It's not permissions as I can rename .thumbs to 'thumbs' and works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a security rule set up in Apache's global configuration that denied access to any folder prefixed with a '.' (e.g. .git):

```
# Deny access to any folder starting with a period (.).
<DirectoryMatch "^\.|\/\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

I had to add two rules above it to allow access to directories that *should* be allowed access—namely, `.well-known` and `.thumbs`:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^\.|\/\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
<DirectoryMatch "/.well-known">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</DirectoryMatch>
<DirectoryMatch "/.thumbs">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Not sure why Magento's wysiwyg uses a dot-prefixed directory for files intended for public access (or at least private admin access)—it seems a lot of people end up running into this error, judging by a Google search on ".thumbs wysiwyg magento 403 access denied"!

Comment: See related answer, but for Nginx instead of Apache: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89618/403-error-on-wysiwyg-image-previews