magento2.4.7 wysiwyg media images not showing on fronted
I've just upgraded magento from 2.4.0 to 2.4.7, but now when I upload image into media gallery so, image not showing on frontend but working fine on backend.
https://i.imgur.com/MM3wSxc.png
https://i.imgur.com/kyyNDDY.png
Does anyone know how to fix this?

try this if you using nginx https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/89705/51548

Thanks @Rizwan that's work for me..

This is caused by wrong file permission. So try to execute the following commands:
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;

sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;

sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;

sudo chmod u+x bin/magento


i also tried above solution but that didn't work for me...
